# Using Property Setter In __init__

Tags: python

How do I use a Property setter in `__init__` without pylint complaining that the attribute has been defined outside `__init__`?

For example, the following code only produces one exception which is caught in the try clause at the bottom.

```
class CircleNotUsingSetterInInit(object):

    def __init__(self, radius):
        # Notice underscore in 'self.radius
        self._radius = radius

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        if radius < 0:
            raise ValueError("Radius must be non-negative")
        self._radius = radius


class CircleUsingSetterInInit(object):

    def __init__(self, radius):
        # Notice lack of underscore in 'self.radius'
        self.radius = radius

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        if radius < 0:
            raise ValueError("Radius must be non-negative")
        # From pylint:
        # Attribute '_radius' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
        self._radius = radius


CircleNotUsingSetterInInit(5)
CircleNotUsingSetterInInit(-1)
CircleUsingSetterInInit(5)
try:
    CircleUsingSetterInInit(-1)
except ValueError:
    print("caught exception")
```

I'm using Python 2.7.10.

Comment: `CircleUsingSetterInInit` is the correct behaviour, feel free to ignore `pylint` on this one, or turn it off with an inline comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is completely safe to ignore in this case. Pylint just doesn't "see" that, it's rather complex to notice without doing syntax parsing.

You can add a comment for pylint to disable this warning locally like this:

```
class CircleUsingSetterInInit(object):

    # ....

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        if radius < 0:
            raise ValueError("Radius must be non-negative")
        # pylint: disable=W0201
        self._radius = radius
```

---

`W0201` is the code for `attribute-defined-outside-init`, which is the warning you receive according to [the docs](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html). You should always add such disable comments as close to the source as possible, so that pylint works normally for the rest of the file.

Comment: Note that you can just use `disable=attribute-defined-outside-init`, which means the reader doesn't need to look up the code!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, oh yes, since pylint v0.25.3 I believe

Comment: That's right: http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#do-i-have-to-remember-all-these-numbers