# Problem with the Property-Setter decorator: "private" attribute is not being setted

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, methods, python-decorators

I am having serious dificulties finding out why my "Setter Decorator" from my custom Class (Data_Setter_Class) is not working properly.

I found out that my "Private" Attribute (self.__Data) is not being properly setted by my Decorated Method (self.Data).

Therefore, once I instanciate my "Data_Setter_Class", and I try to access its Data attribute by its property decorator method, I get an error saying that my class simply doesn't have the "__Data" attribute.

Description of my custom class: it is a class that should test the structure of my data according to some stablished rules (type of the Data object, data dimensions...).

The Python version I am using: 3.6.4

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd


class Data_Setter_Class(object):
    def __init__(self, Data):
        """

        This Class allows one to evaluate the best probability distribution function (PDF), \
        and its relative best parameters for the given Series (array).


        """
        self.Data = Data


    @property
    def Data(self):
        print("\n\n\tEis os Dados\n\n")
        return self.__Data

    @Data.setter
    def Data(self, data_entry):

        print("Iniciando a análise dos dados inseridos")
        print("Eis o cabeçalho deles: \n\n", data_entry.head(), '\n\n')

        if isinstance(data_entry, np.ndarray) and np.ndim(data_entry) >1:
            Chosen_Dimension = int(input("The data has more than one dimension (1D). \
                                         Choose what dimension the distribution fit analysis should be applyed: \n\n "))

            self.__Data = data_entry[Chosen_Dimension]


        elif isinstance(data_entry, pd.DataFrame):
            if np.ndim(data_entry) >2:

                Chosen_Dimension = input("The data has more than one dimension (1D). \
                                         Choose what dimension the distribution fit analysis should be applyed: \
                                         \n\n {0} \n\n".format(data_entry.keys()) )

                while Chosen_Dimension not in data_entry.keys():
                    print("Dimension not properly set. Choose between the options given!")

                    Chosen_Dimension =input("Choose what dimension the distribution fit analysis should be applyed: \n\n {0} \n\n".format( self.data_entry.keys() ) )

                print("Dimension/Attribute Selected: ", Chosen_Dimension)

                self.__Data = data_entry.loc[:,Chosen_Dimension]

                self.Chosen_Dimension = Chosen_Dimension


        elif isinstance(data_entry, gpd.GeoDataFrame):
            if np.ndim(data_entry) >2:

                Chosen_Dimension = input("The data has more than one dimension (1D). \
                                         Choose what dimension the distribution fit analysis should be applyed: \
                                         \n\n {0} \n\n".format(data_entry.keys()) )

                while Chosen_Dimension not in data_entry.keys():
                    print("Dimension not properly set. Choose between the options given!")

                    Chosen_Dimension =input("Choose what dimension the distribution fit analysis should be applyed: \n\n {0} \n\n".format( self.data_entry.keys() ) )

                print("Dimension/Attribute Selected: ", Chosen_Dimension)

                self.__Data = data_entry.loc[:,Chosen_Dimension]

                self.Chosen_Dimension = Chosen_Dimension



        elif isinstance(data_entry, pd.Series):

            self.__Data = data_entry


        elif isinstance(data_entry, np.ndarray):
            if np.ndim(data_entry) ==1:
                self.__Data = data_entry


        elif isinstance(data_entry, np.array):
            if np.ndim(data_entry) ==1:
                self.__Data = data_entry


        else:
            try:
                self.__Data = np.array(data_entry)

            except:
                print("Data Format out of order. Try setting it up to 1D array object like before applying to the Best Fit Distribution Function")



        print("Eis o data_entry após todo o teste de dados: \n\n", data_entry.head(), '\n\n')



    @property
    def Chosen_Dimension(self):
        print("This is the numerical attribute selected for the analysis: ", str(self.__Chosen_Dimension))

        return self.__Chosen_Dimension


    @Chosen_Dimension.setter
    def Chosen_Dimension(self, chosen_dimension):

        self.__Chosen_Dimension = chosen_dimension


if "__main__" == __name__:


    Temporal_data = pd.date_range(start='1995/12/31', end='2000/12/31', freq='D')
    Size = Temporal_data.size 

    Random_Array = pd.DataFrame({'Precipitacao': np.random.randint(low=0, high=350, size=Size)}, 
                                index=Temporal_data)



    Data_Setter_Object = Data_Setter_Class(Data=Random_Array)

    Random_Array = Data_Setter_Object.Data
```

The message error that appears:

AttributeError: 'Data_Setter_Class' object has no attribute '_Data_Setter_Class__Data'

I thank you for your time, and I hope hearing from you soon.

Sincerely yours,

Answer (score 0):

I did not know this either before but the syntax for the "hidden" variable with getters and setters is '_var_name' not '__var_name' for what you are trying to do. Change your __init__ method to this.

```
def __init__(self, Data):
    """

    This Class allows one to evaluate the best probability distribution function (PDF), \
    and its relative best parameters for the given Series (array).


    """
    self._Data = Data
```

and similarly in the @property and @Data.setter methods refer to the variable as self._Data instead of self.__Data

Example other question that uses this:
[Using Property Setter In __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383581/using-property-setter-in-init)

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property